# Get the status of changed options in default iOS calendar setting from our iOS application through EventKit or any other ways?

Tags: ios, iphone, calendar, ekeventstore, ekeventkit

[image]

Is it possible to get the status of the option that the user are choosing in default iOS calendar from our iOS application programatically ? ,Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

From my research we cannot get to access other application preference as apple is restricting that we can only access our own app preference ,If we try access other application preference apple might reject your application .Hope this save time for someone seeking for the answer.